# Can an Oauth2 authorization server call the redirect_uri using POST?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm trying to find out if the Authorization Code grant allows the server to call the redirect_uri using POST.

In my experience most authorization servers use GET but I stumbled upon one case (Acuity Scheduling API) which calls the redirect_uri using POST.

Is this a violation of the spec or is it expected?

I went through the OAuth2 spec and several online sources. I cannot find a definitive source that confirms this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tore described this is a valid option that is part of the spec. To achieve this behaviour you should start the authorization flow with the parameter `response_mode=form_post`. This will instruct the authorization server to return the HTML form that Tore describes.

This behaviour is covered by two specs:

- https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html Introduces the `response_mode` authorization request parameter
- https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html Defines the `form_post` response mode.

Comment: Thanks for providing the sources! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

It is totally fine and usually the preferd way to post the authorization code to the client. How it is done, is that the authorization server returns a HTML page with a hidden HTML form. That then is auto-submitted using JavaScript to the client.

The form can look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: session=s%3A99AF5HUWVOclLXJjEWxKIxUSu-XES_Im.Yr39g9QIZ%2FSnmZ84NsYAxNc... 

<html><head><title>Submit This Form</title></head>
<body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
  <form method="post" action="https://example.com/Account/LoggedIn">
    <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="bMJgE4X4FuL6PNRxxdByKJfruEA..."/>
    <input type="hidden" name="expires_in" value=“3600"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="token_type" value="Bearer"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="36819"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...XXX...eEA_ZCF4"/>
  </form>
</body></html>
```

The important thing to realise is that it is the browser doing the actual POST, not the authoirization server.